# Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba, types, vlookup

I am trying to find an Employee name and their Import date from a spreadsheet called CashReward.

The coding below is appearing with an error message 'Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class'. I have tried changing the data type to `CDate` and `CStr` but no use.

`concat = EmpName & GetDate`

```
BasicSal = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CVar(concat), Sheets("CashReward").Range("G3:K" & Cashlastrow), 2, False)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What sort of data is in column G of your worksheet?

Comment: It is the Employee name and their Import date. so it is formatted like 'Richard Smith18/03/2013  11:05:43'

Comment: This seems to be working for me. Why are you using the `CVar()` function on your `concat` variable? How is `concat` dimensioned -- as a string?

Comment: Try `BasicSal = WorksheetFunction.Match(concat,Sheets("CashReward").Range("G:G"), False)` and let me know what it returns.

Comment: An error message saying unable to get the match property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: This error happens when your search string is not found in the given range. Please post the workbook file if you have any more questions. You can upload to GoogleDocs or DropBox.

Comment: In your code, do `debug.print concat` and what appears in the Immediate window? Then copy this value and do a Ctrl+F to find that value in Column G. What happens?

Comment: It says it can't find it even though it is definitely there in Column G, thanks for help by the way. Much appreciated

Comment: The code works when I literally type in the search string, it is very odd

Comment: Seems like that would happen when the value of the variable <> the value that you type in to the formula manually.  Can't really help without seeing the workbook, and the value(s) that are causing this error.

Comment: It is working now, it had something to do with the formatting of the cells. It was putting two spaces between the date and time, thats why it wasn't recognizing it. Thanks for all your help

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking my answer as "accepted", or @GTG's answer (or both if possible). We both suggest that the reason this is failing is because the values were inconsistent, which turns out to be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This happens if your search string is not found in the given range.

Note that the data in the range needs to be sorted in ascending order, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

> The values in the first column of table_array must be placed in
>   ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP may not give the correct
>   value. You can put the values in ascending order by choosing the Sort
>   command from the Data menu and selecting Ascending. For more
>   information, see Default sort orders.

Comment: The range is definitely right, I have double and triple checked. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yeah the search string is right. I think it has something to do with the data type as it works when I do it with just Employee name without the import date

Comment: The concat variable will contain a string.  This should be a simple string match, so if concat contains a string that exists in column G and the range is sorted, then this should work.

Comment: I tried it by just typing in the vlookup search and it worked fine. The variable is causing problems but I'm not sure why, I have tried changing the data type of the variable but still no use

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I just ran into the same issue where a previously-working WorksheetFunction.VLookup suddenly stopped working. This happened after I did some variable name cleanups. All I changed was the capitalization of names to make them more readable (none of the changes were to the argument vars in the vlookup - that entire statement was unchanged). Luckily I have a backup copy of the module so I can just paste that back in, but I am curious as to whether anyone has figured out why the function starts behaving in this way for no apparent logical reason.

Answer (score -2):

Amy one can solve this erroe run time error '424' object require

```
Private Sub VLOOKUP()
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer

For I = 2 To 14

For J = 1 To 1
For K = 2 To 2


Sheet2.Cells(I, K) = Appliaction.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(Sheet2.Cells(I, J), Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$C$307"), 2, False)
Next K
Next J
Next I
```

End Sub