# excel VBA runtime error - 1004

Tags: vba

I'm just trying to do something very simple with Vlookup, but am getting the 1004 error. Would really, really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance. Here's my code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim user As String
    Dim drawn As String
    Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("consolidated")

    For i = 2 To 2092
        user = CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value)
        Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sections")
        drawn = CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(user, Sheet.Range("A2:B3865"), 2))
        Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("consolidated")
        Cells(i, 10).Value = drawn
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? On what line does the error occur?

Comment: yes - it occurs on the line i use vlookup. sometimes i get the object-defined error 1004, and sometimes i get the error that says "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: could it just be because it doesn't find the first user of "consolidated" listed in "sections"? I assumed that vlookup doesn't give an error if something is not found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503199/unable-to-get-the-vlookup-property-of-the-worksheetfunction-class

Comment: thanks reband. i already saw that thread and it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: I've also see `Application.VLookup`, omitting the `WorksheetFunction` part. I'm not sure, but something to try.

Comment: if i wanted vlookup to simply return a 0 if the search term is not found, how would i change my code?

Comment: thanks so much neizan - i took out WorksheetFunction and every ActiveWorkbook, and using the ThisWorkbook object for the code, it ran perfectly.

Comment: Just as a side note, the `Cells` property refers to the active worksheet. This means that when you run the above code when `"consolidated"` is active or when `"sections"` is active, results will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use VLOOKUP as a member of WorksheetFunction, an error will result in a runtime error. When you use VLOOKUP as a member of Application, an error will result in a return value that's an error, which may or may not result in a runtime error. I have no idea why MS set it up this way.

If you use WorksheetFunction, you should trap the error. If you use Application, you should use a Variant variable and test for IsError.  Here are a couple of examples.

```
Sub VlookupWF()

    Dim sUser As String
    Dim sDrawn As String
    Dim shSec As Worksheet
    Dim shCon As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set shSec = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sections")
    Set shCon = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("consolidated")

    For i = 2 To 2092
        sUser = shCon.Cells(i, 1).Value
        'initialize sDrawn
        sDrawn = vbNullString

        'trap the error when using worksheetfunction
        On Error Resume Next
            sDrawn = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sUser, shSec.Range("A2:B3865"), 2, False)
        On Error GoTo 0

        'see if sdrawn is still the initialized value
        If Len(sDrawn) = 0 Then
            sDrawn = "Not Found"
        End If

        shCon.Cells(i, 10).Value = sDrawn
    Next i

End Sub

Sub VlookupApp()

    Dim sUser As String
    Dim vDrawn As Variant 'this can be a String or an Error
    Dim shSec As Worksheet
    Dim shCon As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set shSec = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sections")
    Set shCon = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("consolidated")

    For i = 2 To 2092
        sUser = shCon.Cells(i, 1).Value
        vDrawn = Application.VLookup(sUser, shSec.Range("A2:B3865"), 2, False)

        'see if vDrawn is an error
        If IsError(vDrawn) Then
            vDrawn = "Not Found"
        End If

        shCon.Cells(i, 10).Value = vDrawn
    Next i

End Sub
```